# *could not find libmount* when cross-compiling glib-2.5

Tags: compiling, glib

I'm trying to cross-compile for my embedded target but libmount/libmount.h could not be found:

```
(... compile process)
checking for LIBMOUNT... no
checking libmount/libmount.h usability... no
checking libmount/libmount.h presence... no
checking for libmount/libmount.h... no
configure: error: *** Could not find libmount
```

I've also installed libmount-dev package and re-run the configuration parameters:

```
export TARGET_DIR=/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/
export glib_cv_stack_grows=no; \
export glib_cv_uscore=no; \
export ac_cv_func_posix_getpwuid_r=no; \
export ac_cv_func_posix_getgrgid_r=no; \
CFLAGS=-I${TARGET_DIR}usr/include \
LDFLAGS=-L${TARGET_DIR}usr/lib \

./configure --prefix=${TARGET_DIR}glibArm --host=arm-hisiv400-linux
```

Greatly appreciate any comments from anyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error while I was compiling an image for the emulator Gemun(versatile)
I resolved the problem by typing these commands:

```
make qemu-arm-versatile-defconfig
```

(// try `cd configs` Then `ls`to show the list of supported boards).

```
make menuconfig (your custom system banner .....)
make
```

if you have any problems with missing gcc compiler try this:
Install the GCC, G++ cross compilers and support programs by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-armel-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

If you are using an Arietta, Aria or FOX board:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

If you are using an Acqua board:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```